# CI/CD GitHub: React App on Dev Domain with Plesk Server

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, cicd, plesk-onyx

I am currently building multiple react apps and it'd be awesome to be able to continously deploy them from a github repo to a dev domain for the clients to be able to access them. I was able to setup a webhook through GitHub Actions whenever I merge pull requests to the master branch so that Plesk pulls the current code and deploys it. Now I thought I could simply add two [additional deployment actions](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/git-support/using-remote-git-hosting.75848/#enable-additional-deployment-actions) to the git repo settings in plesk to get it to work:

```
    /opt/plesk/node/17/bin/npm install &> npm-install.log
    /opt/plesk/node/17/bin/npm run build &> npm-build.log
```

The first would obviously install NPM dependencies and the second would build a production bundle in the /build folder (both outputs were logged). I then setup a very simple .htaccess file to redirect traffic into that subdirectory (I was told this would be the easiest way to make routing work as well).

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !build/
    RewriteRule (.*) /build/$1 [L]
```

Everything works like a charm, when I install dependencies on my local machine and upload them manually. Installing dependencies through Plesk works as well. Somehow, I can't get my system to build a production bundle though. The build log is as follows:

```
    > testing@0.1.0 build
    > react-scripts build
    
    /var/www/vhosts/VIRTUALHOST/ROOTDIRECTORY/node_modules/universalify/index.js:15
      }, 'name', { value: fn.name })
                             ^
    
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
        at exports.fromCallback (/var/www/vhosts/VIRTUALHOST/ROOTDIRECTORY/node_modules/universalify/index.js:15:26)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/VIRTUALHOST/ROOTDIRECTORY/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:57:27)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/VIRTUALHOST/ROOTDIRECTORY/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:5:6)
```

I then tried to run the build process through SSH, same outcome. Multiple different NPM/Node Versions, same outcome. I have been googling for an hour now without any luck but it'd really be worth it for me cause I see myself using that CI/CD Workflow a lot more often in the future if I can somehow get it to work.

If anyone has any different recommendations for CI/CD Workflows or thinks that my idea is not best practice, I am eager to learn!

**Thanks for the feedback**

---

## Edit 1

So I was able to get it to work over SSH by installing [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script). Problem is that somehow the deployment actions still don't use the correct version (the user that is being used to perform these actions is the same I am logged in through SSH but it's using a different NPM and node version nonetheless). I am starting to get annoyed cause I simply don't understand what's wrong! :D

## System Specs:

**OS Release**
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

**Plesk Version**
18.0.41 Ubuntu 18.04 1800220207.23

**Node Version**
v17.7.2 (but tested on several other Versions as well)

**NPM Version**
8.5.2

Core bootstrapped with create-react-app (5.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

After having thought about it, I thought that maybe writing a custom build script that sourced the user's .bashrc file again would work and... voilà!

So to reiterate, my workflow is as follows (still open for suggestions): I push commits to my GitHub Repo, I merge the development branch to my master, as soon as the pull request is merged, a GitHub Action triggers a webhook setup by my Plesk Server, which in turn pulls all code changes, installs all requried dependencies and builds a production package. My domain points to the base directory, but a .htaccess file (provided above) redirects all requests into the build directory.

Hope this is helpful to someone.